Eliminating complex numbers from solutions
In Maple
eq:=ln(y)-1/2*ln(1+y^2) = x-c1;
solve(eq,y)


In Mathematica
eq = Log[y] - 1/2*Log[1 + y^2] == x - C[1]
sol = Solve[eq, y]


This is just one example out of many. I prefer the Maple form.
I can remove the complex in this specific example doing something like
eq = Log[y] - 1/2*Log[1 + y^2] == x - C[1]
sol = SolveValues[eq, y]
sol /. any_/Sqrt[any2_] :> 1/Sqrt[any2*any^2]


But this is all done in code without seeing the expressions. So not easy to do each time.
Is there a way to automate this more? Using ExpToTrig and such did not help. FullSimplify with special complex function or transformation function might do it but I have not tried that yet.  Simplify and FullSimplify as is, do not change it.
Any one can suggest a way to make Mathematica produce similar output as Maple above, but without manual transformation as I did above since this will have to work in general.  Something like this will be nice
sol = Solve[eq, y, ReduceNumberOfComplexNumbersInSolution->True]

But there is no such option for Solve.
V 14
Update
I just noticed that if I do
eq=Log[y]-1/2*Log[1+y^2]==x-C[1]
sol=SolveValues[eq,y,Reals]

It gives

So may be Maple's default solve assumed reals? do not know why. ( I am translating my Maple code to Mathematica and in Maple it just did solve with no options, that is why I asked).
But for now, will add this assumption in the Mathematica version.

is this an answer: powTrans[e_] := e /. Power[a_, 1/2] :> I  Power[-a, 1/2] and then (for {sol1, sol2} = y /. Solve[eq, y]),  FullSimplify[sol1, TransformationFunctions -> {powTrans, Automatic}]  I tried to penalize the occurrences of Complex[0,a_] with a Complexity function, but got nowhere with that.

Reals is the first thing I thought of, but that answer is already in the OP. It is most likely the most robust approach, although it does generate conditional expressions.
The follow also work:
Solve[eq, {x, y}]
(* warnings omitted
{{y -> -(E^x/Sqrt[-E^(2 x) + E^(2  C[1])])},
 {y -> E^x/Sqrt[-E^(2 x) + E^(2  C[1])]}}
*)

eq2 = Log[y] - 1/2*Log[1 + y^2] == x - a;
sol = Solve[eq2, {y}]
(*
{{y -> -(E^x/Sqrt[E^(2 a) - E^(2 x)])},
 {y -> E^x/Sqrt[E^(2 a) - E^(2 x)]}}
*)

eq3 = Log[y[1]] - 1/2*Log[1 + y[1]^2] == x[1] - C[1];
sol = Solve[eq3, {y[1]}]
(*
{{y[1] -> -(E^x[1]/Sqrt[E^(2  C[1]) - E^(2 x[1])])},
 {y[1] -> E^x[1]/Sqrt[E^(2  C[1]) - E^(2 x[1])]}}
*)

I believe whether a -1 gets factored out of the square root has to do with variable ordering. However that's just a guess based on the ordering of the exponentials.

Here is an alternative technique using TransformationFunctions.
eq = Log[y] - 1/2*Log[1 + y^2] == x - C[1]

{sol1, sol2} = y /. Solve[eq, y]

FullSimplify[sol1, TransformationFunctions -> {powTrans, Automatic}]

where
powTrans[e_] := e /. Power[a_, -1/2] :> I  Power[-a, -1/2]

Addendum
To try something new as I was exploring, I played around with a ComplexityFunction as well to reduce the count of I;
e.g.,
cf[w_][e_] := 
 w  Count[e, Complex[0, a_], Infinity] + LeafCount[e]

which didn't work:
Manipulate[
 With[{simped = 
    FullSimplify[sol1, ComplexityFunction -> cf[w]]}, {simped, 
   cf[w][simped]}], {{w, 0}, 0, 1000}]

Maybe someone else has a good idea for a ComplexityFunction
